# Some questions about similar matrices and linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Similarity of matrices gives an equivalence relation on $M_n(F)$, so I can define $S$ to be the set of equivalences classes. Can I define a bijective function $\Phi$ from $S$ to $\mathcal{L}(V)$? (My gut says 'yes' - perhaps I can map an equivalence class of similar matrices to the linear operator that they represent?) And if so, is there a way to define a binary operation on $S$ that turns $\Phi$ into an isomorphism, with addition on $\mathcal{L}(V)$ defined as usual?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, just add matrix representatives and consider the equivalence class of the sum.  Then check that it's well-defined.

Comment: What is $L(V)$?

Comment: @AsinglePANCAKE: you'll find that pretty difficult, as the sum is in fact _not_ well-defined.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oops.  And methinks $L(V)=Hom_F(V,V)$ here...

Comment: @AsinglePANCAKE: and what is $V$? (I'm being intentionally dense here.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan.  Ah, okay.  Then I shall intentionally stop...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan A vector space over some field $F$...I know you're trying to get at something, but I don't know what!

Comment: @Bach: I am trying to get at the fact that you talked about $M_n(F)$ and then talked about $L(V)$ without specifying the relationship between these two things.

Answer (score 2):

No. If you compute the sizes of the two sets when $F$ is a finite field, you will find that they disagree. If you try to define addition on equivalence classes, you will find that it is not well-defined.

Comment: I see what you are saying under the comments. I should have been more specific. Does this change if I consider only infinite fields like $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Bachmaninoff it does, but not in a useful way.